# material-ui styles with next.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components

I'm having trouble getting material-ui styles to work correctly with next.js. When I change a style and then save while running the dev server the styles get applied, but if I reload the page, save any other change, or restart the server the default material-ui styles overwrite my custom styles. Also, whenever I use the Box material-ui component I see this error in the console:

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-3 makeStyles-boxStyles-1" Client: "MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-4 makeStyles-boxStyles-1"
```

Here is my _document.tsx: https://pastebin.com/wJD9jyZQ

Here is my _app.tsx: https://pastebin.com/s8Ys01kb

Here is my index.tsx: https://pastebin.com/t5Z9QGpP

Here is index.styles.ts (where my custom styles are): https://pastebin.com/qe7M5ysq

Answer (score 2):

In the `_document.js` file you need to enhance the `App` with the ServerStyleSheets object.

For Material UI **v4** you need to import:

```
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

For Material UI **v5** you need to import:

```
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

Then later down in the file:

```
const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();

...

enhanceApp: (App: any) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App ... />),
```

See this [v4 example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js)

The above worked for me with **v5** even though the v5 example did not include `ServerStyleSheets`